# Different plots in the same figure when using clear

Tags: image, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have 3 .m files and each one plots a graph. I need to superimpose the results from the three of them, so what I did is to copy the three codes into a single .m file.

The problem is that I need to clean (by using the command "clear"), between every program, and therefore, between every plot.

Anyone has any suggestion on how to plot the three results in a single figure, please?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: It is not ideal to have lots of variables at the top level (command line scope). If you wrap your scripts inside a function the variables are cleared automatically when the function returns (as they go out of scope). Worth thinking about.

Comment: Why not convert the scripts to functions that output the data to plot so you can gather it in one place?

Comment: @excaza - I was writing that in an answer as you posted your comment… :-)

Comment: yeah, that's a nice idea!! I will try that! The only issue is that I have lots of variables, but it sounds like the best option! thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following approach: a single file containing four functions.

```
function plotEverything()
  [x1 y1] = data1();
  [x2 y2] = data2();
  [x3 y3] = data3(0.5);
  figure
  plot(x1, y1);
  hold all;
  plot(x2, y2);
  plot(x3, y3);
  title 'my awesome plot of everything';
  xlabel 'X'; ylabel 'Y';
  legend({'one', 'two', 'three'});
end

function [x y] = data1()
  x = 1:5;
  y = 0.5 * x;
end

function [x y] = data2()
  x = 2:2:10;
  y = sqrt(x);
end

function [x y] = data3(p)
  x = linspace(0,7,15);
  y = 0.1 * rand(size(x)) + p * x.^2;
end
```

Put it al in the file `plotEverything.m`, and call it from the command line with `plotEverything`. No need to explicitly clear any variables - anything that was created in any of the functions will be gone by the time the last function returns, and anything created by the individual functions (note I called everything `x`, `y` - that was deliberate) is invisible to the other functions as it has local scope.

Now the code is organized - there is a function just for plotting, and a function for generating the data that goes into each of the plots. Obviously your functions `data1` etc will be more complicated than mine, but the idea is the same.

Comment: thank you very much for that example!! I will try that or also, as I have every program in a different script, I will turn them into functions, as you mentioned before, so I have everything more organized. Otherwise I will have more than 600 lines of code in the same file.. :O Thank you very much! Really nice help!

Comment: Glad you like it. Of course you can keep the functions in different files - just making them into functions and returning only the values to be plotted is sufficient to make everything work much more cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this line:

```
clearvars -except YourVariables
```

In which YourVariables are the ones you want to keep.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about `clearvars - except ...`. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I believe as you clear you variables after each script , that means you do not need the variables from one script to run the other. So you can use this

```
figure; %// a figure will open up
hold on;
call script 1
clear;
call script 2
clear;
call script 3;
clear;
```

Noe the figure opened at the start will have all the superimposed plots.

Also **take care** that none of your scripts should call `figure` command(they can call `plot` command) or else a new figure will open up and plots will not be superimposed

Comment: This ought to work if the individual scripts are well constructed. I would recommend, if possible, to leave the _calculation_ in three separate files but putting all the _plotting_ commands in a single file. This makes it easier to see at a glance how the plot is constructed while leaving the details of what gets plotted in the other files.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm going to do! thank you for this clarification, I'd probably get wrong with this too if you don't tell me! thankss!!! :D